# Why does replacing a POST argument in a JSR223 PreProcessor leave it removed on subsequent iterations?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I'm changing a couple of POST request values using an JSR223 PreProcessor with the following code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;  
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;

def length = 10 // the size of the random string
def pool = ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', 0..9, '-'].flatten() // generating pool
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())

def randomChars = (0..9).collect { pool[random.nextInt(pool.size())] }
def randomString = randomChars.join()


Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments();
for (int i=0;i<arguments.getArgumentCount();i++)
{
  Argument argument = arguments.getArgument(i);
  String name = argument.getName();
  String value = argument.getValue();
  if(name =="mainForm:firstName"){
    sampler.getArguments().removeArgument("mainForm:firstName");        
    sampler.addArgument("mainForm:firstName",randomString); 
    log.info("Name is " + randomString);
}


if(name =="mainForm:covers:0:sumInsured"){
      sampler.getArguments().removeArgument("mainForm:covers:0:sumInsured");
    value = value.replace("\$","");
    value = value.replace(",", "");
    def val = Double.parseDouble(value);
    val++;
                sampler.addArgument("mainForm:covers:0:sumInsured","\$"+String.valueOf(val)); 
    }
}
```

I can see log output for the first iteration, but there's nothing for subsequent ones suggesting the arguments are no longer found for some reason.

I have this PreProcessor attached to the HTTP Request it's modifying.

Any idea why it's only being run once?

I notice in the source for Arguments it mentions isRunningVersion() - what does this do?

```
    public  void addArgument(Argument arg) {
    TestElementProperty newArg = new TestElementProperty(arg.getName(), arg);
    if (isRunningVersion()) {
        this.setTemporary(newArg);
    }
    getArguments().addItem(newArg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [HTTPArgument](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/HTTPArgument.html) instead of generic Argument like:

```
sampler.addArgument(new HTTPArgument("mainForm:firstName",randomString));
```

Also check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries and inspect what's being sent via [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

Also be aware that you can implement your requirement without using scripting at all, check out the following [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction):

- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - generates string of a given length from the given source characters
- [__strReplace](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) which is the wrapper around [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dimitri,
 Turns out that the simplest solution was to modify the argument in-situ rather than trying to replace it:

```
argument.setValue(randomString);
```